# Stop replacement by pattern?

Tags: python

Say my file look like this:

```
some lines
tom
some lines
beginword a b
some lines
endword
jim
some lines
beginword x y
some lines
endword
...
```

Want to be:

```
some lines
tom
some lines
beginword ZZ b
some lines
endword
jim
some lines
beginword x y
some lines
endword
```

So this is my python code:

```
input = open("file", "r")
output = open("file_updated", "w")
dummy = ""
item = []
for line in input:
    dummy += line
    if line.find("tom" + "\n") != -1:
        for line in input:
            if line.find("beginword") != -1:
                item = line.split()
                dummy += item[0] + " w " + item[-1] + "\n"
            else:
                dummy += line
output.write(dummy)
input.close()
output.close()
```

It replace all lines contain "beginword", include the lines belong to "jim", how can I stop the replacement by "endword" belong to "tom"?

Answer (score 0):

Use [break](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) statement

```
input = open("file", "r")
output = open("file_updated", "w")
dummy = ""
item = []
for line in input:
    dummy += line
    if line.find("tom" + "\n") != -1:
        for line in input:
            # check for endword and exit for loop  
            if line.find("endword" + "\n") == 0:
                dummy += line                    
                break

            if line.find("beginword") != -1:
                item = line.split()
                dummy += item[0] + " w " + item[-1] + "\n"
            else:
                dummy += line
output.write(dummy)
input.close()
output.close()
```

Also, have a look at these:

- [reading and writing files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)
- [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)

Comment: Adding two lines like your, the line contain "endword" belong to tom gone

Comment: I had edited my answer immediately after I posted to change the if condition and added `dummy += line` .. do you still see that line gone?